# Need Assistance: Unable to get datetime as x ticks with bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, visualization

I am trying to make a combined graph for one of my systems. I am trying to visualize time series data using bar chart along with line chart(with step).
This is a time series data therefore, I want to show datetime in the x label.

When I plot bar chart with **df2['datetime'].index** I get plots as expected but I do not get datetime as x-ticks. I believe that this is because I am using **df2['datetime'].index**.

When I plot bar chart with **df2['datetime']** I get datetime in x-ticks however, the plot does not look realistic.

I am also attaching a snapshot of my data for better understanding. Any suggestions will be useful. Thank you.

```
fig,(ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (24,12))
ax0.bar(df2['datetime'].index, df2['T1'], width = 1, color='blue', align = 'edge', alpha = 0.5, label ='T1')
ax0.bar(df2['datetime'].index, -1*df2['T2'], width = 1, color='red', align = 'edge',alpha = 0.5, label ='T2')
ax0.step(df2['datetime'].index, df2['T3'], color='blue', linewidth=2, where = 'post', label ='T3')
ax0.step(df2['datetime'].index, -1*df2['T4'], color='red', linewidth=2, where = 'post', label ='T4')

ax00 = ax0.twinx()
ax00.step(df2['datetime'].index, df2['A1'], color='b', linestyle = '--', linewidth=1, where = 'post', label ='A1')
ax00.step(df2['datetime'].index, df2['A2'], color='r', linestyle = '--', linewidth=1, where = 'post', label ='A2')
ax00.set_ylabel('L2', fontsize=12, color='black')

ax0.set_ylabel("L1", fontsize=12, color='black')
ax0.set_xlabel("Datetime", fontsize=12, color='black')
ax0.set_title('Zone 2', fontsize=16, color='black')
ax0.grid(True)
ax0.legend(loc='upper left',fontsize = 12)
ax00.legend(loc='upper right',fontsize = 12)

ax1.bar(df2['datetime'], df2['T1'], width = 1, color='blue', align = 'edge', alpha = 0.5, label ='T1')
ax1.bar(df2['datetime'], -1*df2['T2'], width = 1, color='red', align = 'edge',alpha = 0.5, label ='T2')
ax1.step(df2['datetime'], df2['T3'], color='blue', linewidth=2, where = 'post', label ='T3')
ax1.step(df2['datetime'], -1*df2['T4'], color='red', linewidth=2, where = 'post', label ='T4')

ax01 = ax1.twinx()
ax01.step(df2['datetime'], df2['A1'], color='b', linestyle = '--', linewidth=1, where = 'post', label ='A1')
ax01.step(df2['datetime'], df2['A2'], color='r', linestyle = '--', linewidth=1, where = 'post', label ='A2')
ax01.set_ylabel('L2', fontsize=12, color='black')

ax1.set_ylabel("L1", fontsize=12, color='black')
ax1.set_xlabel("Datetime", fontsize=12, color='black')
ax1.set_title('Zone 1', fontsize=16, color='black')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.legend(loc='upper left',fontsize = 12)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
ax01.legend(loc='upper right',fontsize = 12)
plt.show()
```

[image: Attaching output of this code]
[image: Attaching sample data for reference]

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably comes from `width = 1`, because using datetime, a width of 1 is not equal to the size between two datapoints.

Try to use a smaller width in

```
ax1.bar(df2['datetime'], df2['T1'], width = 1, color='blue', align = 'edge', alpha = 0.5, label ='T1')
ax1.bar(df2['datetime'], -1*df2['T2'], width = 1, color='red', align = 'edge',alpha = 0.5, label ='T2')
```

You can also compute what exact width you need, but I'll let you search how to do that ;)

Comment: Right: width=1 means one day.   You probably want `width=1/24`, or `width=np.timedelta64(1, 'H')` should also work.